# Data from Future disappears

Tags: android, flutter, dart, future

I need to get data from API and put it in a ListView. It occures by pressing FloatingActionButton calls "_refresh()" method. It recieves 10 cats and put it in the list. 
In this method I calls another method "_builtListView()", which should create a ListView element and its Cat rows, but seems like cats disappears in another method despite the fact that it happens in one class.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  var catList = new List<Cat>();

  void _refresh() {
    var catsFuture = fetchCats();
    catsFuture.then((catList) {
      print("Future cats catch: " + catList.length.toString() + " cats.");
      _builtListView();
    });
    setState(() { });
  }

  Future<List<Cat>> fetchCats() async {
    // getting cats code
    print("fetchCats(): " + catListFetched.length.toString() + " cats.");
    return catListFetched;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _builtListView(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _refresh,
        tooltip: 'Refresh',
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _builtListView() {
    if (catList.isEmpty)
      print("_builtListView, catList is empty!");
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: catList == null ? 0 : catList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text("Text " + index.toString()),  //catList[index].toString()),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

What have I see in console:

```
I/flutter (10172): _builtListView, catList is empty!
//_refresh
I/flutter (10172): _builtListView, catList is empty!
I/flutter (10172): fetchCats(): 10 cats.
I/flutter (10172): Future cats catch: 10 cats.
I/flutter (10172): _builtListView, catList is empty!
```

What don't I get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is on `_refresh` function. When you handle the future, at `then` you never assign the `catList` value to `catList` (`List<Cat>`). A simple fix would be:

```dart
void _refresh() {
    var catsFuture = fetchCats();
    catsFuture.then((_catListResult) {
      catList = _catListResult;
      print("Future cats catch: " + catList.length.toString() + " cats.");
      _builtListView();
    });
    setState(() { });
}
```